# Will awaiting multiple tasks observe more than the first exception?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await

Today my colleagues and I discussed how to handle exceptions in C# 5.0 `async` methods correctly, and we wondered if awaiting multiple tasks at once also observes the exceptions that do not get unwrapped by the runtime.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
async Task ExceptionMethodAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    throw new Exception();
}

async Task CallingMethod()
{
    try
    {
        var a = ExceptionMethodAsync();
        var b = ExceptionMethodAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(a, b);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Catches the "first" exception thrown (whatever "first" means)

    }
}
```

What happens to the second task now? Both will be in a faulted state, but is the second task's exception now observed or unobserved?

Comment: The book C# in depth discussed this problem, you can find answer there.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` returns a task and like all tasks the `Exception` property holds an `AggregateException` that combines all exceptions.

When you `await` such a task only the first exception will actually be thrown.

> ... Whether because of child tasks that fault, or because of combinators like Task.WhenAlll, a single task may represent multiple operations, and more than one of those may fault.  In such a case, and with the goal of not losing exception information (which can be important for post-mortem debugging), we want to be able to represent multiple exceptions, and thus for the wrapper type we chose AggregateException.

> ... Given that, and again having the choice of always throwing the first or always throwing an aggregate, for “await” we opt to always throw the first

from [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/)

It's up to you to choose if you want to handle just the first using `await task;` (true in most cases) or handle all using `task.Exception` (as in my example below), but in both cases `a` and `b` would not raise an `UnobservedTaskException`.

```
var task = Task.WhenAll(a, b);
try
{
    await task;
}
catch
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions.Select(e => e.Message)));
}
```

Comment: Should we call `task.Exception.Handle(_ => true)` on the catch or are the child exceptions marked as "handled" by using `await`?

Comment: @jorgebg I assume `Task.WhenAll` "handles" the exceptions of all the individual tasks. All you need to do is handle the exception of the compound task `Task.WhenAll` returns. So AFAIK, `await Task.WhenAll(...)` is enough.

Comment: When I need to handle each task's exception separately and know which task it comes from, I guess I could iterate all tasks I passed to `Task.WhenAll` and check their `Exception`, instead of using the combined task's `Exception`, right?