# How can I send HTTP GETs to several URLs using .NET async code and get the first result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I understand async javascript but aync .NET has a different approach and I still haven't got my head around it properly.

I have a list of URLs that I would like to check. I would like to check them asynchronously and get the first one that returns a certain status code. In this case I am looking for status code 401 (Unauthorized) as this indicates that it is a login challenge, which is what I am expecting. So I can't just use `Task.WaitAny` because I need to run some code to see which one matches my status code first.

Can anyone give me an example of how you run a callback on an aync task and then stop all the other tasks if you found what you want?

I am using .NET 4 in this project and would prefer to stick with this if possible. I have the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` nuget package installed.

**UPDATE:**
I have put together the following code, which I have finally got to produce the correct results, except I think it is waiting for each task - missing the whole point of being async. Not sure about use of `new Task()` or `t.Wait()` within the inner task but it seem the only way to catch the exception. (Exceptions happen on DNS fail and connection timeouts - I don't know a better way to handle those than catching and ignoring the exceptions.)

Any advice on improving this code to make it actually async?

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test() {
        //var patterns = GetPatterns();
        var patterns = "http://stackoverflow.com/,https://www.google.com,http://www.beweb.co.nz,https://outlook.office365.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync,http://rubishnotexist.com".Split(",").ToList();

        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        string result = "";
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var pattern in patterns) {
            var url = pattern;

            Task task = new Task(() => {
                string answer = "";
                var st = DateTime.Now;
                var t = httpClient.GetAsync(pattern, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
                t.ContinueWith(d => {
                    if (!source.IsCancellationRequested) {
                        if (t.IsFaulted) {
                            answer = "Fault - " + " " + url;
                        } else if (d.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                            // found it - so cancel all others
                            answer = "YES - " + d.Result.StatusCode + " " + url;
                            //source.Cancel();
                        } else {
                            answer = "No - " + d.Result.StatusCode + " " + url;
                        }
                    }
                    result += answer + " ("+(DateTime.Now-st).TotalMilliseconds+"ms)<br>";
                });
                try {
                    t.Wait();
                } catch (Exception) {
                    // ignore eg DNS fail and connection timeouts
                }
            });

            allTasks.Add(task);
            task.Start();
        }

        // Wait asynchronously for all of them to finish
        Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());

        return Content(result + "<br>DONE");
    }
```

In the above I didn't have the cancellation part working. Here is a version including cancellation:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test2(string email) {
        var patterns = GetPatterns(email);
        patterns = "http://stackoverflow.com/,https://www.google.com,http://www.beweb.co.nz,https://outlook.office365.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync,http://rubishnotexist.com".Split(",").ToList();
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        string result = "";
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var pattern in patterns) {
            var url = pattern;

            Task task = new Task(() => {
                string answer = "";
                var st = DateTime.Now;
                var t = httpClient.GetAsync(pattern, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
                t.ContinueWith(d => {
                    if (!source.IsCancellationRequested) {
                        if (t.IsFaulted) {
                            answer = "Fault - " + " " + url;
                        } else if (d.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                            // found it - so cancel all others
                            answer = "YES - " + d.Result.StatusCode + " " + url;
                            result += answer + " (" + (DateTime.Now - st).TotalMilliseconds + "ms)  <-- cancelled here <br>";
                            source.Cancel();
                        } else {
                            answer = "No - " + d.Result.StatusCode + " " + url;
                        }
                    } else {
                            answer = "cancelled - " + url;
                    }
                    result += answer + " (" + (DateTime.Now - st).TotalMilliseconds + "ms)<br>";
                });
                try {
                    t.Wait();
                } catch (Exception) {
                    // ignore
                }
            });

            allTasks.Add(task);
            task.Start();
        }

        // Wait asynchronously for all of them to finish
        Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());

        return Content(result + "<br>DONE");
    }
```

Comment: What about just using `Task.WhenAll()` instead, then examine the results of the tasks (assuming you include the HTTP response status code in the returned value)?

Comment: I will try Task.WhenAll but some of the requests might take a long time so I would like to exit and stop the others when I found one.

Comment: You can create a single `CancellationToken` that you pass to all the tasks, and on the first failure you cancel it.  All the tasks then observe the token (either by passing on to those async methods that support it, or by explicitly checking it occasionally), and exit when it's cancelled.

Comment: So I would use `Task.WhenAll()` with a cancellation token?

Comment: No you need to pass the `CancellationToken` to all the tasks instead.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899842/how-to-cancel-and-raise-an-exception-on-task-whenall-if-any-exception-is-raised/41900329#41900329) has a detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: Also how can I ignore exceptions?

Comment: I've rolled the above comments and further into an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Task.WhenAll()` instead, then examine the results of the tasks.

To prevent other tasks continuing once any one throws an exception, you can create a single `CancellationToken` (by first creating a `CancellationTokenSource`, then using its `.Token`) that you pass to all the tasks, and on failure, you cancel the token; see [How to cancel and raise an exception on Task.WhenAll if any exception is raised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899842/how-to-cancel-and-raise-an-exception-on-task-whenall-if-any-exception-is-raised/41900329#41900329) for more details and sample code. All the tasks then observe the token, and optionally explicitly check it occasionally and exit if it's canceled.  They should also pass it on to those methods that support it, so they, in turn, can cancel quickly when the token is canceled.

Re exceptions, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912899/will-awaiting-multiple-tasks-observe-more-than-the-first-exception) covers them pretty well.  If you want no exception thrown into the calling code, you should handle the exception within each task create instead, but then you will need to modify the above canceling mechanism accordingly.  You could instead just catch the single exception that `await Task.WhenAll()` might throw and at that point observe all the exceptions thrown in the `Task.Exception` property of each task, or ignore them if that is the desired result.

---

Re canceling on success (from the comments) - I guess there are many ways to do it, but one could be:

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<HttpStatusCode>>();

    foreach (var url in patterns)
    {
        tasks.Add(GetStatusCodeAsync(url, cts.Token));
    }

    while (tasks.Any() && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Task<HttpStatusCode> task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        if (await task == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            // Handle the "found" situation
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            tasks.Remove(task);
        }
    }
}
```

and then put your `HttpClient` code in a separate method:

```
private static async Task<HttpStatusCode> GetStatusCodeAsync(object url, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        // Your HttpClient code
        // ...
        await <things>;
        // (pass token on to methods that support it)
        // ...
        return httpStatusCode;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Don't rethrow if you handle everything here
        return HttpStatusCode.Unused; // (or whatever)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. As soon as one throws an exception the others stop but I need them to keep going. How do I create a task that wraps the httpclient task and catch the exception? Should I use new Task() or does this use a new thread unnecessarily? The exception does not appear to be thrown on task creation but only if I add a Wait(), is that the right thing to do?

Comment: In a truly async situation, you want to completely avoid `.Wait()` and `.Result` as they are blocking calls.  Those are both taken care of by `await` instead.  You almost certainly want to avoid `new Task()` and should not need it; simply calling a method that returns a `Task` or `Task<TResult>` creates, starts, and eventually returns the task.  I'd recommend reading Stephen Cleary's [primer](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and (best practices)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); it covers all this.

Comment: If you don't want the other calls to stop, just don't use the cancellation mechanism I described.  Re catching the `HttpClient` exception, you can do this inside the code for each task and not let the exception bubble up into the `await`.

Comment: To clarify I dont want the other calls to stop on exception. I do want the other calls to stop on success.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. Unfortunately that won't work in .NET4 as task is not awaitable, I guess that's why I fell into using Waits. `Task.WhenAny` isn't defined. Looks like I may need to upgrade the project. Also, what should this code be? `Your HttpClient code` and how can the return value `return HttpStatusCode.Unused` be converted to a `Task<HttpStatusCode>`?

Comment: There is [a way to async-wait on .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4), but if you're able to upgrade your projects I'd recommend doing that instead.  The return is correct if - as I expected you would - you use any `await` within that method; the compiler magically handles converting the result to a `Task<result>`.  I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I've upgraded to .net 4.5 and this is working well!