# How to return AggregateException from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, aggregateexception

I got an async method working like an enhanced `Task.WhenAll`. It takes a bunch of tasks and returns when all are completed.

```
public async Task MyWhenAll(Task[] tasks) {
    ...
    await Something();
    ...

    // all tasks are completed
    if (someTasksFailed)
        throw ??
}
```

My question is how do I get the method to return a Task looking like the one returned from `Task.WhenAll` when one or more tasks has failed?

If I collect the exceptions and throw an `AggregateException` it will be wrapped in another AggregateException.

**Edit: Full Example**

```
async Task Main() {
    try {
        Task.WhenAll(Throw(1), Throw(2)).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.Dump();
    }

    try {
        MyWhenAll(Throw(1), Throw(2)).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.Dump();
    }
}

public async Task MyWhenAll(Task t1, Task t2) {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    try {
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
    }
    catch {
        throw new AggregateException(new[] { t1.Exception, t2.Exception });
    }
}
public async Task Throw(int id) {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Inner" + id);
}
```

For `Task.WhenAll` the exception is `AggregateException` with 2 inner exceptions.

For `MyWhenAll` the exception is `AggregateException` with one inner `AggregateException` with 2 inner exceptions.

**Edit: Why I am doing this**

I often need to call paging API:s and want to limit number of simultaneous connections.

The actual method signatures are

```
public static async Task<TResult[]> AsParallelAsync<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> source, int maxParallel)
public static async Task<TResult[]> AsParallelUntilAsync<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> source, int maxParallel, Func<Task<TResult>, bool> predicate)
```

It means I can do paging like this

```
var pagedRecords = await Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
                                   .Select(x => GetRecordsAsync(pageSize: 1000, pageNumber: x)
                                   .AsParallelUntilAsync(maxParallel: 5, x => x.Result.Count < 1000);
var records = pagedRecords.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

It all works fine, the aggregate within aggregate is just a minor inconvenience.

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve]. If I try your code, I only get a single `AggregateException`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u6EVSE

Comment: I assume your question is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912899/will-awaiting-multiple-tasks-observe-more-than-the-first-exception

Comment: Why not propagate the exception thrown by WhenAll, rather than catching it and throwing your own? Or use WaitAll?

Comment: @canton7, thank you for your reply. Propagate the aggregateexception from WhenAll makes no difference. It is still becomes an aggregate inside an aggregate.

Comment: Somewhat related: [I want await to throw AggregateException, not just the first Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` methods are designed to only every set at most a single exception on the returned task, not multiple.

This leaves you with two options, you can either not use an `async` method to start with, instead relying on other means of performing your method:

```
public Task MyWhenAll(Task t1, Task t2)
{
    return Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .ContinueWith(_ => Task.WhenAll(t1, t2))
        .Unwrap();
}
```

If you have a more complex method that would be harder to write without using `await`, then you'll need to unwrap the nested aggregate exceptions, which is tedious, although not overly complex, to do:

```
    public static Task UnwrapAggregateException(this Task taskToUnwrap)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        taskToUnwrap.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                if (task.Exception is AggregateException aggregateException)
                    tcs.SetException(Flatten(aggregateException));
                else
                    tcs.SetException(task.Exception);
            }
            else //successful
                tcs.SetResult(true);
        });

        IEnumerable<Exception> Flatten(AggregateException exception)
        {
            var stack = new Stack<AggregateException>();
            stack.Push(exception);
            while (stack.Any())
            {
                var next = stack.Pop();
                foreach (Exception inner in next.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (inner is AggregateException innerAggregate)
                        stack.Push(innerAggregate);
                    else
                        yield return inner;
                }
            }
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any indication that he wants to flatten a hierarchy of AggregateExceptions?

Comment: @canton7 The whole point of a general is to cover the general case, not write code that'll error or behave improperly if there's more than one aggregate exception nested in one other aggregate exception.

Comment: He's asking how to imitate the behaviour of `Task.WhenAll`, and unwrapping multiple levels of `AggregateException` isn't something that `Task.WhenAll` does.

Comment: @canton7 That solution is attempting to undo the fact that additional layers of aggregate exceptions were added manually to code to get around the fact that `async` methods don't support providing multiple exceptions.  Rather than writing to code to only work for a single example, it's coded to work regardless of how many aggregate exceptions are added and regardless of how they're aggregated.  `Task.WhenAll` doesn't need to deal with that.  If you think it's better to write a solution that simply breaks if there isn't exactly one aggregate exception in one aggregate exception, you can.

Comment: Thanks, the method isn't that complicated. I'll try your "manual" continuation and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: `.ContinueWith(t => Task.WhenAll(t.Result)).Unwrap()` worked exactly as I wanted. Marked as answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TaskCompletionSource`.

The outermost exception is created by `.Wait()` or `.Result` - this is documented as wrapping the exception stored inside the Task inside an `AggregateException` (to preserve its stack trace - this was introduced before `ExceptionDispatchInfo` was created).

However, Task can actually contain many exceptions. When this is the case, `.Wait()` and `.Result` will throw an `AggregateException` which contains multiple `InnerExceptions`. You can access this functionality through [`TaskCompletionSource.SetException(IEnumerable<Exception> exceptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.setexception?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCompletionSource_1_SetException_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Exception__).

So you do *not* want to create your own `AggregateException`. Set multiple exceptions on the Task, and let `.Wait()` and `.Result` create that `AggregateException` for you.

So:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
tcs.SetException(new[] { t1.Exception, t2.Exception });
return tcs.Task;
```

Of course, if you then call `await MyWhenAll(..)` or `MyWhenAll(..).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, then it will only throw the first exception. This matches the behaviour of `Task.WhenAll`.

This means you need to pass `tcs.Task` up as your method's return value, which means your method can't be `async`. You end up doing ugly things like this (adjusting the sample code from your question):

```
public static Task MyWhenAll(Task t1, Task t2)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var _ = Impl();
    return tcs.Task;

    async Task Impl()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        catch
        {
            tcs.SetException(new[] { t1.Exception, t2.Exception });
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, though, I'd start to query why you're trying to do this, and why you can't use the `Task` returned from `Task.WhenAll` directly.

Comment: By awaiting the tcs task you defeat the entire purpose of doing this, as it'll only throw the first exception if there are multiple.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if only some of the tasks throw.

Comment: @Servy I know. I copied his code, and adjusted it. I've no idea what he's actually trying to write -- I assume he knows that this bit of his code is incorrect, and was only for illustration.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about tcs but couldn't really work out how to use it. I'll look closer at your example as see if it gets better this time.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer, because I found a simpler solution. This solution does not involve the pesky `ContinueWith` method or the `TaskCompletionSource` type. The idea is to return a nested `Task<Task>` from a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), and [`Unwrap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) it from the outer container function. Here is a basic outline of this idea:

```
public Task<T[]> GetAllAsync<T>()
{
    return LocalAsyncFunction().Unwrap();

    async Task<Task<T[]>> LocalAsyncFunction()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<T>>();
        // ...
        await SomethingAsync();
        // ...
        Task<T[]> whenAll = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return whenAll;
    }
}
```

The `GetAllAsync` method is not [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async). It delegates all the work to the `LocalAsyncFunction`, which is `async`, and then `Unwrap`s the resulting nested task and returns it. The unwrapped task contains in its [`.Exception.InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions) property all the exceptions of the `tasks`, because it is just a facade of the internal [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) task.

Let's demonstrate a more practical realization of this idea. The `AsParallelUntilAsync` method below enumerates lazily the `source` sequence and projects the items it contains to `Task<TResult>`s, until an item satisfies the `predicate`. It also limits the concurrency of the asynchronous operations. The difficulty is that enumerating the `IEnumerable<TSource>` could throw an exception too. The correct behavior in this case is to await all the running tasks before propagating the enumeration error, and return an `AggregateException` that contains both the enumeration error, and all the task errors that may have occurred in the meantime. Here is how it can be done:

```
public static Task<TResult[]> AsParallelUntilAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> action,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate, int maxConcurrency)
{
    return Implementation().Unwrap();

    async Task<Task<TResult[]>> Implementation()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<TResult>>();

        async Task<TResult> EnumerateAsync()
        {
            var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency, maxConcurrency);
            using var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            while (true)
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) break;
                var item = enumerator.Current;
                if (predicate(item)) break;

                async Task<TResult> RunAndRelease(TSource item)
                {
                    try { return await action(item); }
                    finally { semaphore.Release(); }
                }

                tasks.Add(RunAndRelease(item));
            }
            return default; // A dummy value that will never be returned
        }

        Task<TResult> enumerateTask = EnumerateAsync();

        try
        {
            await enumerateTask; // Make sure that the enumeration succeeded
            Task<TResult[]> whenAll = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            await whenAll; // Make sure that all the tasks succeeded
            return whenAll;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Return a faulted task that contains ALL the errors!
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Prepend(enumerateTask));
        }
    }
}
```