# How to execute a Polly policy for all elements of an IEnumerable, and stop on first unhandled exception

Tags: c#, async-await, polly, retry-logic, bulkhead

The policies of the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library, for example `Bulkhead`, `Retry` etc, contain a method `ExecuteAsync` with many overloads (18), but none of them allows to execute the policy for all elements of an `IEnumerable` and gather the results. It seems that the whole library is focused on the goal of executing a single action, leaving the responsibility of managing multiple executions to the client code. I would like to fix this omission by implementing an extension method for all Polly policies (all implementations of the [`IAsyncPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/IAsyncPolicy.cs) interface), with the signature below:

```
public static Task<TResult[]> ExecuteAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this IAsyncPolicy policy,
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> action,
    bool continueOnCapturedContext = false,
    bool onErrorContinue = false)
```

The `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter controls whether to continue on the captured synchronization context, and should just be passed
to the native `ExecuteAsync` method:

```
Task<TResult> IAsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(
    Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    bool continueOnCapturedContext);
```

The `onErrorContinue` parameter is the most important aspect of this question, since it controls the behavior in case of a policy failure. My intention is to use this extension method with thousands of elements, and in case of any exceptions that are not expected/handled by my policy¹ I would like to terminate the whole execution promptly and gracefully. In case the argument `onErrorContinue` has the default value `false`, the first unhandled exception should cause the cancellation of all pending operations, and the whole execution should terminate as soon as all started operations have completed. In the opposite case of `onErrorContinue: true`, all elements should be processed by the policy. Finally all exceptions should be propagated, bundled in an `AggregateException`, independently of the `onErrorContinue` value.

How could I implement this extension method?

Hypothetical usage scenario of this method:

```
var policy = Policy
    .BulkheadAsync(maxParallelization: 10, maxQueuingActions: Int32.MaxValue)
    .WrapAsync(Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3,
            sleepDurationProvider: n => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 * n))
    );

var urls = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(n => n.ToString());
var random = new Random(0);
string[] results = await policy.ExecuteAsync(urls, async url =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate a web request
    lock (random) if (random.NextDouble() < 0.66)
        throw new HttpRequestException($"Url #{url} failed");
    return url;
}, onErrorContinue: false);
```

¹ <sub>This should happen rarely in production, but may happen frequently during the development, and could hurt productivity.</sub>

Comment: Note, I am asking this question with the intention of [answering it myself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I will postpone posting my answer for 24 hours, in case that someone would like to attempt to solve this problem without the influence of an already published solution.

Comment: I'm looking at the [ExecuteAsync overloads](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/d95959fe1449407603c8605282fbba97041fd026/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.ExecuteOverloads.cs) and [ExecuteAsync<TResult> overloads](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/d95959fe1449407603c8605282fbba97041fd026/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.TResult.ExecuteOverloads.cs) and almost each and every overload deals with the `Context` concept. Is it missing intentionally from your design?

Comment: @PeterCsala adding support for the `Context` or even the `CancellationToken` parameter would make the implementation overly complicated. So I am asking for a method offering just the basic functionality. Anyone who wants more than that, will have at least a starting point to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation of the `ExecuteAsync` method. A `CancellationTokenSource` is used for cancelling the pending operations in case of an exception. The `Task.WhenAll` does a good job at ignoring the `OperationCanceledException`s, when there are more important exceptions to propagate. Finally the `Task.WhenAll` task is returned without being `await`ed, in order to preserve all exceptions.

```
public static Task<TResult[]> ExecuteAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this IAsyncPolicy policy,
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> action,
    bool continueOnCapturedContext = false,
    bool onErrorContinue = false)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = !onErrorContinue ? cts.Token : default;
    var tasks = source.Select(async (item) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return await policy.ExecuteAsync(async _ =>
            {
                return await action(item);
            }, token, continueOnCapturedContext);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (!onErrorContinue) cts.Cancel();
            throw;
        }
    }).ToArray();
    var whenAll = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    _ = whenAll.ContinueWith(_ => cts.Dispose(), TaskScheduler.Default);
    return whenAll;
}
```

Emulating the `Task.WhenAll` behavior, which is desirable in this case, [is quite tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687698/how-to-return-aggregateexception-from-async-method/) otherwise (with async/await). So I am happily avoiding this trouble by using a small and [dirty](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) `ContinueWith`, in order to finally [dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource) the `CancellationTokenSource`.

An alternative way of dealing with multiple exceptions is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception). This solution propagates a nested `AggregateException`, which sounds ugly, but in practice it's OK because `await`ing an asynchronous method eliminates one level of nesting anyway.